# "Errors in the encryption library" When restoring Analysis Services Database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2014, msas, analysisservices

I have a AS Database (SQL Server 2005). I need to restore the database in a SQL Server 2014.

When I'm trying to restore the database I have this error:

> File system error: The following error occurred while opening the file
>   '\?\C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\MSAS12.MSSQLSERVER\OLAP\Data\Estadisticasnue.1.db\0.CryptKey.bin'.
>
> Errors in the metadata manager. Processing for the database will be
>   disabled because an error occurred while loading the 'Estadisticasnue'
>   database cryptography key. One possible reason for this error is that
>   the service account has changed.
>
> Errors in the encryption library:
>   Failed to decrypt sensitive data. Possibly the encryption key does not
>   match or is inaccessible because of improper service account change. 
>   (Microsoft.AnalysisServices)

I don't know why I'm having this problem. If I use a database without password, the same problem appears.